# Receiving cmd line arguments as array

Tags: php

Writing a little command-line script at the moment, and I've got it working pretty nicely.

The script loops until the user issues an exit command, during which the user can enter commands like so:

```
I 5 6
```

It denotes an image creation; 5 and 6 are the width and height to be created.

As it stands I can't seem to capture the user's input in an array. I can always get the first letter but never the other two with [`fgetc`](http://php.net/fgetc).

Currently capturing like this:

```
 $input = strtolower(fgetc(STDIN));
```

Can somebody lend a hand?

Comment: Your title seems to be misleading. Do you want to parse command line arguments, or do you want to read text that users can input inside your program on the console?

Comment: http://php.net/fgetc - `c` at the end stands for character. You might want to read more than a single character, perhaps a line: http://php.net/fgets .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$input = explode(" ",strtolower(fgets(STDIN)));
```

fgetc() only reads one caracter, fgets() reads a string

Answer (score 2):

[`fgetc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetc.php) only reads in one character.

What you want to use is [`fgets()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php).

In your case, to get an input line (in lowercase, as you apparently want it) as array, use:

```
$input_line = strtolower(fgets(STDIN));
$input_array = explode(" ", $input_line);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [fgets()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) to read the whole line.